# Directives scope variable does not work in Jade

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I know the title is bad but the situation itself is weird enough to have this title. So here is my jade file - template:

```
img.picture(ng-show='user.info.profilePicUrl', ng-src='{{user.info.profilePictureUrl}}')
img.picture(ng-show="!user.info.profilePicUrl", ng-src="dummyuser.png")
.basicinfo
  h1.fullname
    a(href='profile/{{user.info.username}}') {{user.info.fullName}}
  p.description {{user.info.bio}}
   span.additional
    a.website(href='{{user.info.website}}') {{user.info.website}}
    a.location(href='#') {{user.info.location}}
.follow
  .count {{user.followedBy.length}} Followers
  follow(to-follow-username="user.info.username")
```

In the directive:

```
scope: {
  user: "="
},
controller: function($scope){                                                                                      
    var request = $http({                                                                                            
      method: "get",                                                                                                 
      url: "/users/" + $scope.user.userID + "/getInfo",                                                              
    });                                                                                                              

    request.success(function(data, status, headers, config){                                                         
      $scope.user.info = data;                                                                                       
      console.log($scope.user);                                                                                      
    });                                                                                                              

    request.error(function(data, status, headers, config){                                                           
      console.log("Status");                                                                                         
      console.log(status);                                                                                           
    });                                                                                                              
  },       
templateUrl: "/templates/follower"
```

So here is problem: When I open the page that contains this template and directives, the user is passed to jade above, and every line of it parses the data from `user`, except `profilePicUrl`, and `user.info.username`. The `user.info.username` work fine in the line `a(href='profile/{{user.info.username}}') {{user.info.fullName}}`, but it doesn't work - comes as `undefined` - in the line `follow(to-follow-username="user.info.username")`.

```
img.picture(ng-show='user.info.profilePicUrl', ng-src='{{user.info.profilePictureUrl}}')
img.picture(ng-show="!user.info.profilePicUrl", ng-src="dummyuser.png")
.basicinfo
  h1.fullname
    a(href='profile/{{user.info.username}}') {{user.info.fullName}} //The username is actual username - Works Here
  p.description {{user.info.bio}}
   span.additional
    a.website(href='{{user.info.website}}') {{user.info.website}}
    a.location(href='#') {{user.info.location}}
.follow
  .count {{user.followedBy.length}} Followers
  follow(to-follow-username="user.info.username") //Doesn't work here
```

Comment: What does `p {{ user }}` display?

Comment: Yeah, it only prints the `user` without `user.info`. I edited the question based on this. Added my directive's controller function. How can I make the http call there synchronous?

Comment: I used promise (then()) to accomplish this but the error stands still. Even if the data comes to the jade, Jade expression parses it while `ng-*` do not: `ng-show="!user.info.profilePicUrl"` doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not make the HTTP cal synchronous but re-apply the scope modifications on success:

```
request.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.user.info = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Because of the async HTTP call the template renders right away - (my humble opinion about this) - is there any way to make the template to be rendered after controller's return or `request`s end?

Comment: $apply re-render the template. This should not be the problem. Check data.username contains a string then have you got any error in the console?